# English Dictionary in one text file

Tags: discussion

Is there a free dictionary in one text file or in a database format that I can download please?
Many thanks.

Comment: Excellent question, but it is considered off-topic for the main site. This should be migrated to meta.

Comment: Do you want the definitions, pronunciation, etc, or is just a word list OK?

Comment: Simple definition would be great.

Comment: See [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441975/where-can-i-download-english-dictionary-database-in-a-text-format). Also, see WordNet.

Comment: Many thanks, just what I was looking for. I don't know how to  close the topic, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use [DictionaryForMIDS](http://dictionarymid.sourceforge.net/). It's excellent.  If you use android, it is available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kugihan.dictionaryformids.hmi_android&hl=en).

Comment: Never heard before, thanks.

Comment: I think the OP wants to have a file of words and definitions so they can write their own software using it. They're not looking for a dictionary app.